# How do you extract all zip codes except a zip code?

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to extract all zip codes except 55802 from a text file.

```
\d\d\d\d\d && ^55802
```

I tried to use the regular expression above, but it isn't working.

What should I change?

Comment: That's not a regular expression. And please show how you're trying to use it. Perl code would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
(?!55802)\d{5}
```

That should match 5 digits (\d{5}) except where the text matches (55802) (?!55802 is a negative lookahead)

Comment: @user3015561 - If [pscs](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3316510/pscs)'s answer is acceptable, please consider checking "Accepted."

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, it's best to check on the outside.

```
$zip =~ /^\d{5}\z/ && $zip ne '55802'
   or die("Not a valid zip code\n");
```